# Getting the last x digits from output with grep command

Tags: unix, grep

I need help getting the last 16 digits from the output I get with this command ;

```
cat q5data.txt | grep -o '[0-9]*[0-9]\{16\}'
```

The output I get is :

```
6420029454020029
26787889786973463
92272417810036027222591368318424
1147142436072964
```

And id want the last 16 digits only of the numbers above, so it would look something like this :

```
6420029454020029
6787889786973463
7222591368318424
1147142436072964
```

So yeah, the question is, how would I get the last 16 digits ?

q5data contains this:

```
0111102.82575525572371251FriThuSat32169716436971243.1415  foo100001$$$3.14153
foo`3.1415Green100010blah2.8
2.85720948213811501Purple`WedTueBLACK1869228491762178BLACK$$3.14100001Feb010000
taoblahfoopiGreen010111
VOIDchiOrangeSatNILLVOIDBLACK$$$Sat3.14155378825854705118Mar$WHITEAug`Tue
4421929582063064
2.8$$$$BLACKSun$"blah$ThublahJun2057411253659033Orange$$Sun$$fubar'
BLACKSun8061215743158569Jul'010101`2.8MayFri$$'blah
100001$3.141533.14153taoBLACKWHITE3.141532.8'foo"chi`BLACK$$$3300209361826966
5976364681345632YellowFri"JanWHITEWedWHITE3652470302503667WHITE
1237496282374608WHITEpiNILLVOID110111WHITEApr'$$$2.83536505910579946111010
54891762211716313.14$$RedWedtaoMonFri110010$$3068508931421361$PurpleNILLWHITE9242959892278294Sep
000110BlueOct2582940799974379
phifoo$
Purple3.1415Green '
3.14BLACKTuepiYellowWHITEchi35798399298233973.14153.1415WHITEpitao$SunBlue010110
NULLBLACKTue1650665049652872`2.8$'$$$NULL3.14SatGreen$$3.141533.14153GreenVOIDJul"
chichifubarWedpiBLACK3.14153BLACKpiWHITEThu$ BLACK
blah2.8fubar4411479881441554$$`BLACKWHITE1101113.14SepWHITEJanThuGreen
$$WHITE'"3675572769992033fooBlueNULL100000'
BLACK 3.14WHITEDecfubarOrangeMay NILLWHITE2570850288634750 101011$$$Mon
Tue" 3.143.14phiSat7665425103246257MayphiTue'0010110101112.8BLACK$fubar"
0358649831711525100010'FriJunThu"3.14SunGreenfubarMonWHITEVOID$$$VOID1877369637528056Jan$010010
GreenTue000111ThuBLACKApr011010
Jun6244216458497289`PurpleAug$$$2685357800265115''2.8taopi101100$$chiFeb
9471418620899225VOID8617331495319240NULLWHITEblah5461478451014026
6352741666667105
WHITEfooOct011010pi$$$110100BLACKBLACKTuePurpleWHITE9093492271343727SepNovchi
Orange3.144596443153024361`"'$$78253311502390510101103.14153Friphi $Mon 
1385825179552755YellowBLACK001011Sep$$RedFebfubarMon010010000010fubar"Jul0110117544560082562350
3.141653642540032022chi'Orange
1253542283769081tao4876457038962098MonSunMayWHITEYellow3.14153$Orange000101blah
RedSatNILLphiVOIDWedfubarGreen chi$$piphiJul$$$111001`9540185369262601NILLVOID
7006440921851679Wed3.14152.8chiGreenThu$$Tuefoofooblahpi$$$taopi$ May 'Feb
MayNILLblah8007182476768737JantaophiThutao$'Jul  AprNILLBLACK'3.14153Feb3.1415
57067714600406493.141537231229468300261Mon$`SunNILL `NULL3.14153foochi1000109494160741986074
6577869219715310JulJanBLACKfubarBLACK2.8phiGreen0091496849086433
SunBlue2355648762601053 3.1415NULL$$$BLACK100011 ThuDecJun2.83.1415phiFeb"
9173525733960126BLACK  3.14153`110001PurpleRedFebfubarVOIDfoo$$$blah9330024102534139 
Jun$$VOIDVOID4099554992034342Julpi9976331355660412taoWHITEGreen$$100010NILLVOID
3.14153phiSatphi43658305924319679197159994746838phipiApr

3.1415RedblahMayfooJul100011NovtaoMon3.141533.14JanGreen$$ OctNILLfooWHITE3.1415
96027197435535111011013.14VOID3583462878046156NULL3.1415blahOrangefoo 100101taofoo3.14153"3.1415
$$Red3.14Marblah'
3797758515388131tao $$$101010NULL2268984774582096BlueBlue3.14153Oct`
74321533961822933.14153994759453326425$$Jul001111PurpleGreenTueNovJan2742714540787707Blue$$$
0010003.14blah3.14ThuWHITE$$$$blah
3997313793176662 3.141463510697622121Yellow 3.1415'Jul`3.14153NILL2.8Thuphi
3134920264311067fooNov`NULL1111119335359393623483Tue$$$GreenVOIDtaoRedTueAug$$3.141532.8Sat'
3.14153Oct100010FebJan$$3.1415pi$$'chiRed$$$NILL8614261680268364

fubarBLACKpi110001110101pichi0126011887834143GreenNILLYellow NILLfoo101000 $$$
RedTueNULLThu2.814091424413091162.8 WHITE$WHITE60620358244865230211111773156587'pi 
Yellow3.1415$$$$$
"Aug3.1415VOIDBLACK0810996065354809$$$NULLfoo$$Orange6850772642048628WedBLACK
BLACKBluepi 70173555329860651869981769139132phi$$$$$$3.14Feb2.86083883638401362
6420029454020029WHITE26787889786973463.14 3.14 Mon`92272417810036027222591368318424$$$tao
fooTue"1147142436072964AprPurpleSep
```

Okay so, at the begining of q5data we see 01111102. and right after this we see : 82575525572371251 (17 digits)
Id like it to output the last 16 digits ( 2575525572371251 )

Thank you :)

Comment: Show your input data

Comment: @hek2mgl Done. Its lots of random text just trying to learn patterns..

Comment: Sorry, typo. About the example, I added it at the bottom of the post @TobySpeight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last 16 digits from every run of 16 or more digits, then you could filter through grep twice:

```sh
grep -Eo '[0-9]{16,}' <q5data.txt | grep -Eo '.{16}$'
```

The first selects all runs of 16 or more digits, and the second selects the last 16 characters from each run.

Testing this on the first line of your input file gives:

```sh
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]{16,}' <<<'0111102.82575525572371251FriThuSat32169716436971243.1415  foo100001$$$3.14153' | grep -Eo '.{16}$'
2575525572371251
2169716436971243
```

Comment: This one does the trick, altho, is there a way of doing it in one run ?

Comment: karakfa's version, using `grep -P`, is the way to achieve this in a single command.  Using pipeline isn't a big deal, though - you're not creating temporary files or anything.

Answer (score 3):

To match the end of the pattern use `\b`

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{16\}\b' q5data.txt
```

so this will match 16 digits up to a word boundary.

Comment: This does not deliver the correct output. The "\b" seems to remove lots of outputs for some reason im not aware of...

Comment: @Jozo The answer gives you the last 16 digits of numbers which are at least 16 digits long. It's working correctly.

Comment: If you look at the very end of the post, I show an example, this number I show in the example is not present in the output by running the command you have provided @hek2mgl

Comment: @Jozo I see, you are right. Let me think about that.

Comment: Do you get " 2575525572371251 " in the output  ? Thats the first number thats supposed to pop out @developer

Comment: @Jozo If you have `GNU` grep you can use: `grep -oP '[0-9]{16}(?![0-9])'`

Comment: @hek2mgl unfortunately this command doesnt do anything for me, have to CTRL C it.

Comment: Of course you need to pass the filename! Otherwise grep will read from stdin. I thought that this is obvious.

Comment: @hek2mgl lol sorry its late and my mind wasnt performing :P yeah it does work.. thank you everyone :)!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to capture digits in strings terminated with non-numerical chars you need negative lookahead (with `-P` option, not available in standard grep)

```
$ grep -Po '[0-9]{16}(?![0-9])'
```

e.g.

```
$ echo "12345678901234567890aaa" | grep -Po '[0-9]{16}(?![0-9])'
5678901234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -Eo '([0-9]{16})$' q5data.txt`